# Excel VBA using Cells properties in a formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, cells

I have created a macro that looks at number in a cell and then copies a group of three columns and inserts them to the right of the group. This all works fine.

I have a formula in a cell after these groups of columns that looks to see if there is a 1 in the cell. the code below is what there would be assuming I created 2 groups.

```
=IF(AND(H9=1,J9=1),1,0)
```

I want to be able to automatically add the M9=1,P=1 if I had created four groups.

If someone has the time to help it would be much appreciated.

Sorry, learning as I go on here.

I am creating a matrix where I can build up a number of functions in the columns direction and a number of inputs that effect the functions in the rows direction.
I start off with a 'group' of three columns per function, In my first group G9 is the expected condition, H9 is the result during simulation and I9 is the result during real world tests. I want to be able to say how many functions and inputs there will be and automatically create the matrix.

If I have two functions then there will be two groups of columns from G to L.

After all of the functions I have a check to see if they all passed, with two functions this check would be in M9, where I have the formula =IF(AND(H9=1,K9=1),1,0) that checks to see if there is a 1 in both H9 and K9 and then puts a 1 in M9.

If I had four functions then I would need the check formula of =IF(AND(H9=1,K9=1,N=1,Q=1),1,0) in S1

I want to create the check formula within a loop so that it adds in the correct cells to check.

Hope this explains it a little bit better, but probably not!!

Here is the code so far

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

' Copy the template worksheet
Worksheets("ZoneTemplate").Copy After:=Worksheets("ProjectConfig")

' Rename the worksheet to the correct Zone
Sheets("ZoneTemplate (2)").Name = Sheets("ProjectConfig").Range("B9")

' Setup the variables
Dim Loop1 As Integer
Dim MySheet As String
Dim NoOfOutputs As Integer
Dim NoOfColumnsOffset As Integer
Dim Loop2 As Integer

' Get the name of the sheet ready for use in the loop
MySheet = Sheets("ProjectConfig").Range("B9").Value  
' Get the number of outputs to add  
NoOfOutputs = Sheets("ProjectConfig").Range("E9") - 1  

' Loop for the number of safety output functions
For Loop1 = 1 To NoOfOutputs
    ' select the columns to copy and copy them to buffer
    Worksheets(MySheet).Range("G:I").Select    
    Selection.Copy
    ' Insert the copied columns infront of J1 and shift everything along to the right
    Worksheets(MySheet).Range("J1").Insert Shift:=xlShiftToRight        
Next Loop1

End Sub
```

Comment: Where did M9 and P come from? What denotes a group? What has your question to do with Cells? There are too many imponderables, please create a clear question.

Comment: in your code you could insert the formula into the cell directly... otherwise I would perhaps use a named range and update the scope of the named range

Comment: there are only two column difference between H and J but between J and M there are 3, what is the correct spacing?

Comment: Sorry I've not done very well at describing my problem.

Comment: And are the groups inserted or is the formula in the same column no matter what?

Comment: Then please show your attempt at creating the dynamic formula in vba.  Show us the vba that creates the group.  Though your description is better we still cannot help without seeing a [MCVE] of the code.

Answer (score 0):

So this did the trick....

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

' Copy the template worksheet
Worksheets("ZoneTemplate").Copy After:=Worksheets("ProjectConfig")

' Rename the worksheet to the correct Zone
Sheets("ZoneTemplate (2)").Name = Sheets("ProjectConfig").Range("B9")

' Setup the variables
Dim Loop1 As Integer
Dim MySheet As String
Dim NoOfOutputs As Integer
Dim NoOfInputs As Integer
Dim NoOfColumnsOffset As Integer
Dim Loop2 As Integer
Dim Loop3 As Integer
Dim loop4 As Integer
Dim SOAddr1 As String
Dim SimAddr As String


MySheet = Sheets("ProjectConfig").Range("B9").Value             ' Get the name of the sheet ready for use in the loop
NoOfOutputs = Sheets("ProjectConfig").Range("E9") - 1           ' Get the number of outputs to add

' Loop for the number of safety output functions
For Loop1 = 1 To NoOfOutputs

Worksheets(MySheet).Range("Safety_Output_Function").Select      ' select the columns to copy and copy them to buffer
Selection.Copy
Worksheets(MySheet).Range("J7").Insert Shift:=xlShiftToRight    ' Insert the copied columns infront of J1 and shift everything along to the right

Next Loop1

' Loop to generate the formula for the Sim Result check
For Loop2 = 1 To (NoOfOutputs)                                  'Sheets("ProjectConfig").Range("E9")

NoOfColumnsOffset = 8 + (Loop2 * 3)                             ' Work out the cell number for the new column
SOAddr1 = Cells(9, NoOfColumnsOffset).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)        ' Convert the cell number to a letter reference
SimAddr = SimAddr & "," & SOAddr1 & "=1"                        ' build the string to add for each column and each time we come round the loop

Next Loop2

' put the new formulas in
Worksheets(MySheet).Cells(9, (NoOfColumnsOffset + 2)).Formula = "=IF(AND(H9=1" & SimAddr & "),1,0)"

' Loop to generate the formula for the Hardware Result check
For Loop3 = 1 To (NoOfOutputs)                                  'Sheets("ProjectConfig").Range("E9")

NoOfColumnsOffset = 9 + (Loop3 * 3)                             ' Work out the cell number for the new column
SOAddr1 = Cells(9, NoOfColumnsOffset).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)        ' Convert the cell number to a letter reference
SimAddr = SimAddr & "," & SOAddr1 & "=1"                        ' build the string to add for each column and each time we come round the loop

Next Loop3

' put the new formulas in
Worksheets(MySheet).Cells(9, (NoOfColumnsOffset + 2)).Formula = "=IF(AND(I9=1" & SimAddr & "),1,0)"


NoOfInputs = Sheets("ProjectConfig").Range("D9") - 1            ' Get the number of Inputs to add

' Loop for the number of safety output functions
For loop4 = 1 To NoOfInputs

Worksheets(MySheet).Range("9:9").Select      ' select the columns to copy and copy them to buffer
Selection.Copy
Worksheets(MySheet).Range("A10").Insert Shift:=xlDown    ' Insert the copied columns infront of J1 and shift everything along to the right

Next loop4

End Sub
```

Comment: Consider indenting your code, also you don't need the () around NoOfInputs, you drop this for the last occurrence. You don't need the .Select and then copy just copy direct , Long is usually better than Integer.

Comment: Thanks for the tips QHarr